# Adding new files since last svn deployment

Tags: svn, repository, springloops

I use springloops to deploy my repo's to my dev and prod web servers. So I have the same CMS in 2 places, and each are a little bit different based on their usage by the dev team or live users. So after searching extensively I need to ask this because my searches contain way too many keywords and no answer is similar or specific enough.

After deploying my repo to the dev or live server, and changing/adding files (via the app, such as uploading a file through the web interface for example) I would like to version the added files. My deployed repo's don't have svn folders.

It looks like I'll have to instead start checking out from the repo, and do a svn update whenever files get added from the back end(??). There must be a way to version files added via the web interface (outside of my local repo) following a deployment?

Thoughts? Links?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your workflow will break at least two rules

- Single point of authoritative changes
- don't place WC in web-space

but - it's **your choice**

Here are proposed and necessary changes to current workflow (maybe some forgotten)

1. dev and prod become WCs of **two different branches** ("...each are a little bit different...") of main repo (DEV and PROD)
2. Changes in trunk (former single sourceof code) merged with branches (two additional WCs for *merge*? and better *visual control*?) and propagaded to servers with `svn up` in servers WC
3. Addeed files will appear in repo's branches after `svn ci`
4. Changes in branches merged (?) into trunk

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Okay, I can have 2 branches, one dev and one prod. When I deploy the *trunk* to the prod server it is following merges with both branches. Here's where my question starts. For example, 2 weeks ago I deploy a finished CMS project trunk to the prod server. Now, the admin who knows enough to be dangerous has installed a module in the CMS, configured it and integrated it into her daily tasks and can't live without it. I need the files she installed *via the web interface* added to the trunk repository.

Comment: 2 weeks ago you deploy code to **trunk**, revision NEW, **trunk** (on revision range OLD-NEW) merged **to PROD** branch, working copy on prod server updated from PROD branch. When some changes was done in PROD working copy on server (it's site also), `svn status` will show modified state of repo. from this repo commit to PROD branch, merge **PROD** branch **to trunk** now, update *your local WC*

Comment: So on the prod server it is a matter of checking out HEAD to use as the production files, instead of doing a "deploy" using springloops. Then when changes are made via the web interface, a commit will be necessary. Is this the idea?